# Why does the accuracy of my "from scratch" implementation of a GRU forward pass decrease with more cells and more timesteps?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

So I've extracted the weights of a model and I wanted to recreate it from scratch. Here's the forward pass I made:

```
class GRULayerCUSTOM(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, ht_prev, Wx_forget, Wh_forget, b_forget, Wx_update, Wh_update,
                        b_update, Wx_state, Wh_state, b_state, return_sequences=False):
        super(GRULayerCUSTOM, self).__init__()
        self.ht_prev = ht_prev
        self.Wx_forget = Wx_forget 
        self.Wh_forget = Wh_forget
        self.b_forget = b_forget
        self.Wx_update = Wx_update
        self.Wh_update = Wh_update
        self.b_update = b_update
        self.Wx_state = Wx_state
        self.Wh_state = Wh_state
        self.b_state = b_state
#         self.returnSeq = return_sequences
#         self.stateList = tf.zeros(shape=(x.shape[0], x.shape[1], 1))
        
    def call(self, x):
        for i in range(x.shape[1]):
        
            inputs = x[:, i, :]
            
            R = tf.sigmoid(tf.tensordot(inputs, self.Wx_forget, axes=1) + tf.tensordot(self.ht_prev, self.Wh_forget, axes=1) + self.b_forget)
            Z = tf.sigmoid(tf.tensordot(inputs, self.Wx_update, axes=1) + tf.tensordot(self.ht_prev, self.Wh_update, axes=1) + self.b_update)
            h_candidate = tf.tanh(tf.tensordot(inputs, self.Wx_state, axes=1) + tf.tensordot(tf.multiply(R, self.ht_prev), self.Wh_state, axes=1) + self.b_state)
#             print(self.ht_prev)
            ht_curr = tf.multiply(Z, self.ht_prev) + tf.multiply((1-Z), h_candidate)
            self.ht_prev = ht_curr
#             self.stateList[0, i, 0] = self.ht_prev
            
#             print(ht_curr)
#         if (self.returnSeq):
#             ht_curr = self.stateList
            
        return ht_curr
```

The model's output when I use only a single timestep (even with multiple cells) is pretty accurate.

Now, if I increase the number of timesteps, but bring down the number of cells to 1, it's still pretty accurate:

[MY OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnISq.png)

[TENSORFLOW MODEL OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA3fE.png)

But the problem is when I have a cell count and timestep count both greater than 1, some outputs from the model are considerably different:

[MY OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/618ku.png)

[TENSORFLOW MODEL OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMstF.png)

Notice, for example, the first row, second column. This is my first post here so I apologize if my post doesn't follow the proper convention! Please let me know and I'll fix it! In any case, I'm hoping someone has an idea as to what might be going on here.